# Setting personal build by default when running a custom build

Tags: teamcity

Is there a way to make teamcity mark personal build by default whenever someone initiates a custom build? (aka builds initiated by teamcity itself should not be personal by default).

This is for `TeamCity Professional 10.0.5 (build 42677)`

Comment: related... https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000004424-Mark-build-as-personal-after-build-run